# How to make double tags in php?

Tags: php, tags

I have some text and double tag in it.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer orci risus, aliquam eget magna eget, condimentum vulputate nisi. *[display=1]Sed dolor risus[/display]*, convallis in vulputate id *[display=0], sodales at sem[/display]*. Suspendisse potenti. Integer quis diam et felis mollis luctus. Phasellus ac dolor risus. In augue ante, iaculis pretium varius sit amet, suscipit quis erat.

I want to php code that get this text from file by *file_get_contents()*, edit text between tags. If number is 1 show it, hide text if number is 0 and always hide tags of course.

This what i want to get on end:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer orci risus, aliquam eget magna eget, condimentum vulputate nisi. *Sed dolor risus*, convallis in vulputate id. Suspendisse potenti. Integer quis diam et felis mollis luctus. Phasellus ac dolor risus. In augue ante, iaculis pretium varius sit amet, suscipit quis erat.

Comment: I've tried to use code from other engine, but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: Can you show that code. Also, why do you want this? Can you not just edit the original to just not have the text you want to hide?

Comment: It just e.g., I can use it for different things
if (stripos ( $tpl->copy_template, "[category=" ) !== false) {
 $tpl->copy_template = preg_replace ( "#\\[category=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/category\\]#ies", "check_category('\\1', '\\2', '{$category_id}')", $tpl->copy_template );
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `preg_replace` you can remove the square block and contents inside the square block based on conditions, like this way:

Try this:

```
$rep = preg_replace("/\[display=0].*?\]|\[.*?\]+/","",$string);
```

[Execute Code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05d3732168ff8b22d5312a5e981937df6b8e2734)

Comment: Some how it doesn't work in my code..
I'm using 2 arrays with tags and replace text.

Comment: @Sergey95 it is working perfectly for me. Also you can see the execution of the code in the mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use a regex, but I see at as an overkill for the simplicity of the task.

If this is going to be shown in a web page, which not just replace the display=0 with an element without any visibility?

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer orci risus, aliquam eget magna eget, condimentum vulputate nisi. [display=1]Sed dolor risus[/display], convallis in vulputate id [display=0], sodales at sem[/display]. Suspendisse potenti. Integer quis diam et felis mollis luctus. Phasellus ac dolor risus. In augue ante, iaculis pretium varius sit amet, suscipit quis erat.";
$text = str_replace("[display=0]", "<span style='display:none'>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[display=1]", "<span style='display:block'>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/display]", "</span>", $text);

echo $text;
```

If it's a console application, or, you want to remove the text from all over the source (not render it at all), then you should use a regex, but I doubt that's the point.

Comment: Well, aren't you searching for an easy way :))

Comment: Nope, cause this variant I know, and this variant don't hide text at all, you still can read it in code.

Comment: It was not your original quesion :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove completly tags and replace them either by what's inside or nothing, here is a recursive function that may help you

```
function change_tags($text)
{
    $start = strpos($text, "[display=1]");
    if($start===false)
        if(($start = strpos($text, "[display=0]")) === false)
            return $text;
    if(($end = strpos($text, "[/display]"))===false)
        return $text;
    $text_to_display = substr($text, $start+11,$end-$start-11);
    $text = str_replace("[display=1]" . $text_to_display . "[/display]", $text_to_display , $text);
    $text = str_replace("[display=0]" . $text_to_display . "[/display]", "" , $text);
    $text = change_tags($text);
    return $text;
}
```

for your example

> $str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer orci risus, aliquam eget magna eget, condimentum vulputate nisi. [display=1]Sed dolor risus[/display], convallis in vulputate id [display=0], sodales at sem[/display]. Suspendisse potenti. Integer quis diam et felis mollis luctus. Phasellus ac dolor risus. In augue ante, iaculis pretium varius sit amet, suscipit quis erat.";

```
echo change_tags($str);
```

The result I get is this

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer orci risus, aliquam eget magna eget, condimentum vulputate nisi. Sed dolor risus, convallis in vulputate id . Suspendisse potenti. Integer quis diam et felis mollis luctus. Phasellus ac dolor risus. In augue ante, iaculis pretium varius sit amet, suscipit quis erat.